# Can calling a complex function inhibit $.when?

Tags: jquery

I have a function:

```
function someFunction(params) {
//Creates an object
//$.each(collection, funct() { /*do work on collection, essentially pushes items into an array */});

//JSON.stringify(results)

//$.ajax POST...this is what I want $.when to wait for

}
```

I setup

```
$.when(someFunction(params)
).then(doNextThing);
```

I also tried

```
$.when(function() {someFunction(params) }
).then(doNextThing);
```

`doNextThing` is invoked before the callback.  Is it possible that `$.each` or `stringify` is causing `$.when` to fail?

Comment: is someFunction returning anything?  It should be returning $.ajax

Comment: There are no `return` statements.  Do you mean I just stick a return in front of $.ajax.  E.G. `return $.ajax{...`?

Comment: doing `return $.ajax` fixed it.  Man, I've been struggling with this for a couple of hours.  If you post an answer I will definitely give you answer credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`someFunction` needs to return an object for `$.when` to work.  Otherwise it is the equivalent of `someFunction(params);$.when(undefined).then(doNextThing)`.  In this setup `doNextThing` will never be called.

Since you are waiting on the ajax call, it should look something like this:

```
function someFunction(params) {
    ...
    return $.ajax(...);
}

$.when(someFunction(params)).then(doNextThing);
```